# Button inside the label with the input does not trigger ng-click

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

That's my code:

```
<label class="item item-input " style="height: 10%" ng-click="publish()">
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title">
<i ng-click="publishBlog()" class="button button-clear icon ion-paper-airplane padding-right"></i>
</label>
```

The "publish()" can  be triggered,but not the "publishBlog()".The ionic will put the icon into the .Does the ionic cause it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

within "label" tag your click event will not work, because label is overriding your button click.

so, use **DIV** instead of **label** , that will work fine.

Comment: @Keval: Unfortunately with this approach label animations when input receives/looses focus are not working (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dma_k/tu9aeag2/2/)): first input has correctly working button but no label animation; second input has not working button but with label animation.

Answer (score 4):

As [Hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4513686/hardy) said, you will have to use `div` instead of `label`. But you will be required to use `$event.stopPropagation();` to make sure only `publishBlog()` gets called. Without `$event.stopPropagation();`, both the functions will get called.

So, here's a sample implementation:

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="my">
    <div class="item item-input " style="height: 10%" ng-click="publish($event)">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title">
        <i ng-click="publishBlog($event)" class="button button-clear icon ion-paper-airplane padding-right"></i>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And your controller:

```
.controller("my", function($scope){  
    $scope.publish = function($event) {
        alert("title");
    };
    $scope.publishBlog = function ($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        alert("icon");
    };    
});
```

Here's a demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/1b82ce25ca44